# How can I attach a PDF in gnus, when I have the PDF attached with org-attach and I view it with PDFView?

Tags: org-mode, gnus, pdf-tools

The PDF is attached like so:

```
***** Model                                                          :ATTACH:
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       f1e5fc57-b85d-4a2c-b064-32523dd11901
:ORG_ATTACH_FILES: patience.RWaR.2023-12-17.p1.r1-1.pdf
:END:
```

As, suggested by NickD (thanks), I can eval:

```
(org-attach-expand "patience.RWaR.2023-12-17.p1.r1-1.pdf")
```

..and get this:

```
"/home/b0ef/data/f1/e5fc57-b85d-4a2c-b064-32523dd11901/patience.RWaR.2023-12-17.p1.r1-1.pdf"
```

This is something I can use in gnus if I use a template

```
<#part type="application/octet-stream" filename="patience.RWaR.2023-12-17.p1.r1-1.pdf" disposition=attachment description=Foo>
<#/part>
```

, but that's quite a tedious process;) Any pointers as to how I can bind this to a key?;)

The best solution would be something like org-attach-dired-to-subtree. For org-mode, I open a Dired buffer next to my org-mode file, then I run that command and the file is attached to the org-mode heading.

Something like that for gnus;)

Comment: The question is a bit broad. Can you be more specific about what you want?

Comment: Bind what to a key?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "This is something I can use in gnus if I use a template, but that's quite a tedious process;) Any pointers as to how I can bind this to a key?"? You seem to think that we know what you are thinking, but we don't so we are trying to puzzle out what you want. I gave it one attempt which apparently did not satisfy you. Before I can try another, I need to know what you want to accomplish: exactly and in detail.

Comment: Right now my whole Xorg crashed, so I need a few days here;). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have an `attachment:` link in your Org mode file, like this:

```
[[attachment:foo.pdf]]
```

You can run `(org-attach-expand "foo.pdf")` in the Org mode buffer to get the complete path name. That's all you need to create a MIME attachment in GNUS.

Adding a src block to your Org mode file like this:

```el
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
(org-attach-expand "foo.pdf")
#+end_src
```

will allow you to run the src block to produce the file path which you can then cut-and-paste into GNUS.